# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.pokemon.filter is not a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Trying to fetch the pokeapi and map through the array of data returned from the api. I set my state to an empty array and then I proceed to try and fetch the api and receive data from the response, and add it to my pokemon state

```
 class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
        super()
            this.state = {
                pokemon: [],
                searchfield: ''
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(pokemon => this.setState({ pokemon: pokemon }))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));    
            }

        onSearchChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({ searchfield: e.target.value })
        }

        render() {
            const filteredPokemon = this.state.pokemon.filter(poki => {
                return 
                   poki.name.toLowerCase().includes
                   (this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
            })
            if (!this.state.pokemon.length) {
                return <h1>Loading</h1>
            } else {
                return (
                    <div className='tc'>
                        <h1>Pokemon</h1>
                        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange} 
                        />
                        <Scroll>
                            <CardList pokemon={filteredPokemon} />
                        </Scroll>
                    </div> 
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you `console.log(this.state.pokemon)` and show us the result ?

Comment: I actually just solved it. When I was setting my state of pokemon to the result of pokemon, it was returning an object rather than an array, so I simply put .then(pokemon => this.setState({ pokemon: [pokemon] })) and it works, thanks for the help though!

Comment: @user80137 that is just adding the object as the single element of a new array - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This api call results in `this.state.pokemon` **being set to an object not an array**:

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(pokemon => this.setState({ pokemon: pokemon }))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I believe you are trying to filter on the `results` property which is an array? In this case, set `this.state.pokemon` to `pokemon.results`:

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(pokemon => this.setState({ pokemon: pokemon.results }))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You could have debugged the fetch to see the object like this:

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(pokemon => console.log(pokemon))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the actual data you receive from the api.

```
{
  "count":949,
  "previous":null,
  "results": [
    {
      "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/1\/",
      "name":"bulbasaur"
    },
    {
      "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/2\/",
      "name":"ivysaur"
    }
  ]
}
```

Change This:

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(pokemon => this.setState({ pokemon: pokemon }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

To

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({results}) => this.setState({ pokemon: results }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```