# TypeError: this.state.robots.filter is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to fetch the Jsonplaceholder users name and id and filter them in in the render method. I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.state.robots.filter is not a function
```

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      robots: [],
      searchfield: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json;
    })
    .then((users) => {
      this.setState({robots: users});
    })
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
    })
  return (
    <div className="container text-center mt-4">
        <h1 className="custom mb-5">RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
        <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Could anyone give me a clue how to solve the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you console log `users`, what is the data or data type?

Comment: Should be `return response.json();`

Comment: [Uncaught TypeError: this.state.pokemon.filter is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416745/uncaught-typeerror-this-state-pokemon-filter-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.json()` not `json`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      robots: [],
      searchfield: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((users) => {
      this.setState({robots: users});
    })
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
    })
   
    return (
      <div className="container text-center mt-4">
        <h1 className="custom mb-5">RoboFriends</h1>
        <input onChange={this.onSearchChange} />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(filteredRobots, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the data type of users below: You are reassigning robots object with users and which should be array, if you want to access filter method. I think you data type of users i not array and that is why its throwing error. try printing users in console.

`.then((users) => {
      console.log(users);
      this.setState({robots: users});
    })`

and correct below **json()** method in your code.

`return response.json();`

Comment: How do I print the users in console here?

Comment: `.then((users) => { console.log(users);
      this.setState({robots: users});
    })` @Umair this how print. If its type of object then you cant have filter method or else it should be. update your json to json() as well

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by appending () to response.json:

```
return response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use fetch rest calling like that

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(res => {
  res.json().then(users => {
    this.setState({ robots: users });
  });
});
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

**response.json** is a promise so you have to call with () something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      robots: [],
      searchfield: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((users) => {
        this.setState({ robots: users });
      })
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
    })
    return (
      <div className="container text-center mt-4">
      <h1 className="custom mb-5">RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
      <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
  </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

refer this link : https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data