# TypeError: this.state.robots.filter is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have been learning how to use React recently and have been taking an online course to do so. I have been having a similar problem as found here [TypeError: this.state.robots.filter is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335179/typeerror-this-state-robots-filter-is-not-a-function) but none of the solutions seem to work. Essentially the code should  pull information from an API and the function in question should filter it depending on the input in the search bar. The terminal says its running successfully but when I check the website I get this response:

[Error displayed on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl4rc.png)

Below is the code I am using

```js
import React from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
import './App.css';




class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            robots: {},
            searchfield: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response=> {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(users => {
            this.setState ({robots: users})
        });
       
    }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value})
    };
    render() {
        const filterRobots = this.state.robots.filter (robots => {
            return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
        })
        return (
        <div className= 'tc '>
       <h1>Robo-Friends</h1>
       <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
       <CardList robots={filterRobots}/>
        </div>
       );
    }
}
export default App
```

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: `this.state.robots` is an object, it should be an array

Comment: Hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` is a function on `array`. Your `robots` variable in state is an object, hence the error says filter does not exist on it. Define it as an empty array in state like so:

```
this.state = {
    robots: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `robots` is an array, not an object, since you are trying to filter/loop through it. Hence, the initial state of `robots` should be defined as an empty array(`[]`).

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    robots: [],
    searchfield: '',
  };
}
```

Side note, you can clean up your filter statement by destructuring the state.

```
const { robots, searchfield } = this.state;
const filterRobots = robots.filter(({ name }) => {
  return name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
})
```

Comment: Same as above, thank you for your help and for the extra destructuring advice!